# Bootstrap sub-nav open on nav hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu and submenu. I achieved the hover on the menu opens the submenu but when the mouse moves to the submenu, it gets closed.

I have added jsfiddle for the html/js I have made. I know I am missing something, but cant find it.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/64r4s8ok/2/

Here is the js script:

```
$(".openSubmenuOnHover").hover(
    function () {
        var thisdiv = $(this).attr("data-target")
        $(thisdiv).collapse("show");
        //$(thisdiv).show("slow");//("show");
    },
    function () {
        var thisdiv = $(this).attr("data-target")
        $(thisdiv).collapse("hide");
        //$(thisdiv).hide();//("hide");
    }
);
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could omit the second handler for `.openSubmenuOnHover` so it won't close if you hover-out.

Then apply a handler to the hover-out event of its container. So it will close only if you hover-out the entire menu.

Like this:

```
$(".openSubmenuOnHover").hover(
    function () {
        var thisdiv = $(this).attr("data-target");
        $(thisdiv).collapse("show");
        //$(thisdiv).show("slow");//("show");
    },
    null
);

$(".containerOf-openSubmenuOnHover").hover(
    null,
    function () {
        var thisdiv = $(".openSubmenuOnHover").attr("data-target");
        $(thisdiv).collapse("hide");
        //$(thisdiv).hide();//("hide");
    }
);
```

What do you think?

EDIT 1:
This answer works by hiding any UL opened before opening the desired UL

Here is the script update:

```
   $(".openSubmenuOnHover").hover(
        function () {
            $(".sub-navbar > ul").each(function (){
                   $(thisdiv).collapse("hide");
            }
            var thisdiv = $(this).attr("data-target");
            $(thisdiv).collapse("show");
            //$(thisdiv).show("slow");//("show");
        },
        null
    );

    $(".containerOf-openSubmenuOnHover").hover(
        null,
        function () {
            var thisdiv = $(".openSubmenuOnHover").attr("data-target");
            $(thisdiv).collapse("hide");
            //$(thisdiv).hide();//("hide");
        }
    );
```

Comment: I got the idea, but this solution will cause the sub-menu once opened, will not close unless I go inside it and then back outside it.

Comment: Here is jsfiddle of your idea https://jsfiddle.net/64r4s8ok/4/ and it confirms my previous comment

Comment: Try this one. Since the two menus are logically related, I assumed the conatiners could be nested and changed the second handler.

https://jsfiddle.net/au8fkekg/

Comment: yeah its fine, I am still facing some issues when populating the other tabs as well .. https://jsfiddle.net/au8fkekg/2/

Comment: I am thinking this will not work with jquery but that there is a solution using css... what do u think ?

Comment: Sorry I've been out for lunch. 

Thanks for the edit request, I approved it. 
Did the edit solve all issues or do you need further help?

Comment: with few modification the issue is completely solved. I appreciate your help  @GigiSan